# PCB Design Power Plane Question

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers, high-speed

I undesrtand that ground plane should be continuous so return current will follow right path so no delay and additional noise voltage along with the reduction of empedance which is good and necessary thing especially for high speed.**(If anything wrong or lack in this part please let me know)**

What bothers me is this: Ground plane has many functions but why do i have to allocate a second layer for vcc plane. If i do then i wont have enough room for wiring in 4 layer since 2 of them already gone for vcc and ground.

Cant i just allocate one layer to continuous ground and use rest for proper trace wiring. And I will draw vcc traces thicker based on current required. I am confused because everyone says allocate power plane besides ground but in high level designs i saw like this [a10-proto kicad](http://www.iuac.res.in/~elab/phoenix/SBC/) there is no power plane only continuous completely allocated ground plane and other layers are for wiring. And they wired power traces with thick wires.

Could you provide me some insight please.

Comment: Why can't you run your traces on plane 1 (and 4)?

Comment: This is not a specific case. I just want to learn from ones who have more experience than me. I want to verify things that i read or know. And in one design things got compilacated and vcc copper was too much it is another reason.

Comment: You don't have to allocate a plane for supplies at all. If you dont have many voltage rails you could lay the power as traces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ground plane is most important, as you recognized.  Not only does it allow the shortest return path, but the lowest impedance, and it also creates minimal loop current which reduces EMI.

The next most important is often the power plane(s).  Usually, once you go to 4-layers, and assign two of them as ground and power, it frees up a lot of routing on the top and bottom layers that you don't need to use the middle planes for routing.  But if it gets tight, yes you can use the power plane for routing some traces.  Often you will have circuits with multiple power rails, and in that case usually the power plane is split into different domains, e.g. the MCU may sit on a section of the board where the power plane is at 3.3V, where other parts of the board are at 12V for I/O.

If the density of the board increases to the point that you find you need more internal layer routing, it might be advisable to go to 6 or more layers.

Again, for most low to medium density boards, having two layers just for routing is usually enough, if your routing strategy is sound.  So if you feel you need additional layers and you aren't packing 0402 or smaller parts close together, then maybe there are better ways to route the traces.  If you do want to put some routing on the power plane (and you can also use the ground plane but I would try to avoid that), just be careful that you aren't cutting of or overly-restricting current paths.

And finally, yes, you could just use one ground plane and three routing layers, if you feel you need more routing area but not enough to justify 6-layers.  So you would just route the power traces as you would normally on a 2-layer board.  Or you could route your signals, then do a copper pour of the power rails in the remaining area.  Remember again to check the current paths.  Usually you route the power traces anyway to be sure you can get sufficient trace widths through everywhere, and maybe do a DRC, then pour the remainder.

EDIT:  Further explanation of the return path.
Current will return along the path of lowest impedance.  In DC or low-frequency circuits, impedance is essentially just the resistance, so current follows the path back with the lowest resistance.  This is usually a ground trace or ground plane.  Current doesn't jump through the air to return on a power trace just because it's closer.

However, when dealing with higher frequencies, impedance is more than just resistance, it includes inductance and capacitance.  Now, the capacitance of a trace will be influenced by a nearby power plane.

If you want to calculate characteristic impedance for example of a 4-layer board with internal ground and power planes, the calculation considers the closest 'reference' plane, which could be either.  So if it is a symmetrical stack up (with equal height from top to first plane as from bottom to second plane), then the impedance of a given track would be the same.  But this assumes the tracks are carrying high-frequency signals, such as USB, Ethernet, etc.

This is where perhaps the confusion in what you have heard or read comes from.  It's sometimes difficult to expand basic electrical theory from the Ohm and Kirchhoff laws, to high-frequency AC circuits, from the DC or time domain, to the frequency domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot AngeloQ. Mostly vcc is not a specific voltage as you indicated (3.3v 5v 1.8v etc.) So i must divide power plane to different voltages. I read that when signal close to power plane than ground plane the return current will be on power plane. Isn't this a problem since signal will pass through differnt voltage blocks. Actually that is why i am a little bit scared from power plane since ground is one huge continuous plane but power plain is mixed. Lastly could you give me a source to understand how to do this properly "not cutting of or overly-restricting current paths."

Comment: The electrical return path will usually be ground, even if there is a power plane closer, which is why the ground is so important.  When it comes to shielding from crosstalk sometimes you will see it shown that you can use ground OR power traces between signal traces, but this doesn't mean the signal return path is the power trace.  The current path along the signal and back along the return path creates essentially a loop antenna.

Comment: [Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza009/szza009.pdf) is a good resource, and [here](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Internal+Power+and+Split+Planes) is another that goes into split planes and some of the issues I mentioned. (vias are usually the main cause of restrictions in split power planes.)  [This](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/n6TskayF1Oc/maxresdefault.jpg) is an image I found online that demonstrates a split plane getting restricted by a high number of vias.  You can see how little cross-sectional copper area there is for current to pass from one side to the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot again :) So finally, i can divide power plane into different voltages(3.3 5 1.8 1.2) and without cutting of or overly-restricting current paths i can draw lines on taht layer too if necessary

Comment: I don't know the details of your circuits, but as a generalization, yes.

Comment: @AngeleO I am  resurrecting the topic :). You said "The electrical return path will usually be ground, even if there is a power plane closer". Is it because the continuous ground plane will have lowest impedance compared to other planes (since its copper width is like pcb size) its impedance becomes so so low.

Comment: @snrIcmn no, because ground usually closes the circuit for many signals.  There are cases where you have differential pairs or similar isolated circuits, but in general, (conventional) current flows from the source through a circuit and back to the ground of the power source.

Comment: @AngeleO Yes in my logic also a circuit should complete itself so it will use ground, therefore a return current should be on a ground layer. However why everyone is keep saying if vcc plane is closer to your signal then it will return from there bla bla. This is just ruining everything. I am trying to learn what is %100 percent correct but everyone says different things

Comment: @snrIcmn, I have added an edit to my answer which hopefully will clarify this for you.

Comment: @AngeleO So basically people generalize things going on in high speed and frequencies to any case. On the other hand for example to calculate a microstrip impedance we use closest plane as referance so in this case this reference plane is also related to our return current?

Comment: @AngeloQ About the power plane, how does one typically use it? Do you assign the whole copper pour of that layer to one net, or do you use it to route power traces and leave the pour unassigned to any net? How do you use it for multiple power nets, and does it make sense to have it assigned to a net if you're only powering one component? You mention the MCU example, but are you splitting the power plane into two separate areas at a different voltage? I never understood how to use a power plane. I typically run traces to all my components for power, which most often tend to be op-amps.